# How to install driver for AMD Radeon R5 Graphics card?

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, ubuntu-drivers

I found instructions on how to install drivers for AMD graphics cards on AMD's website. However, I can't find the model series for my graphics card even after using this websites: https://devicehunt.com. I put in 1002 as the Vendor ID and put 98E4 for the Device ID but all I get is the device name as Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics]. This doesn't match any of the options on this website: https://www.amd.com/en/support.

Output from " lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display' ":

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:98e4] (rev c4)
```

Comment: Hi again Haz :) Just while I remember, now that everything's installed and updated, did removing 'nomodeset' from the grub options still result in the freezing coming back? Ubuntu should be able to install the Graphics drivers itself, so you might not need to install from AMD's website, assuming that the freezing has stopped.

Comment: @pHeLiOn After removing "nomodeset" it still freezes after a short while.

Comment: Does it freeze when booting up or does it go to the desktop and you can use it for a bit and *then* it freezes up? Just curious whether 'nomodeset' just affects booting.

Comment: I also assumed that 'Additional Drivers' would offer Graphics driver installation options.

Comment: @pHeLiOn It allows me to go to desktop and move around for a bit less than a minute before it freezes. The "Additional Drivers" tab still says that no drivers are available.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame - I don't understand why it's not offering AMD Graphics driver options :( According to the Ubuntu Documentation `lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'` should tell you the graphics card info.

Comment: @pHeLiOn I added the output from that command.

Comment: Hmm. Not as helpful as it suggests in the documentation. The closest I've got is the same as you: **Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics]** What about on Windows? Do you have Radeon™ Settings or AMD Catalyst™ Control Center on there? Might offer something less vague than R2/R3/R4/R5...

Comment: @pHeLiOn I have the Radeon Settings as an option to search through but all I got from that was the same as what I wrote in the question.

Comment: Have a read of this at the **Open Source** and **Add The PPA** section: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-amd-radeon-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux. It suggests the Open Source drivers are already installed but can update them further from the PPA if you wish. In 'Settings' program click 'Details' and see what it says under Graphics. I think 'Mesa' is the Open Source graphics driver.

Comment: If I remember correctly, there are proprietary amd/ati/radeon drivers for Ubuntu 14.04.x LTS but not for newer versions, where the free linux drivers should be used, and are working well with newer graphics chips/cards. But there might be problems with some older chips/cards. See for example [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783079/missing-drivers-for-radeon-8470d-on-16-04)

Comment: @pHeLiOn Under the "Graphics Chipset" thing in Radeon Settings it says "AMD Radeon(TM) R5 Graphics".

Comment: That's at least less vague than R2/R3/R4/R5 :) Doesn't help narrow anything down on the AMD Site 'cause there's a LOT of R5 options there. What I meant though was in the Ubuntu 'Settings' program there's a 'Details' tab and it might say 'Mesa' in the Graphics section there. That would suggest that the Open Source drivers are already installed.

Comment: @pHeLiOn The graphics section says: "llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0, 128bits)"

Comment: I think that means it's using software rendering rather than the Graphics card, which suggests that no drivers are installed :( All the documentation suggests it will detect and install the Open Source Graphics Drivers during installation :( Did you try the **Add The PPA** from 5 comments above this one?

Comment: @pHeLiOn Yes I gave it a try but nothing changed : (

Comment: You added the PPA, ran `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade` and rebooted the machine and there was no change? I'm stumped by this one I'm afraid :( This question asks how to find out the Graphics card details so that you can use AMD's site to get the proprietary drivers. Leave the question up and maybe someone with some knowledge will be able to help. At the same time you could start a new question about how the Open Source Radeon R5 graphics driver is not detected or installed. Mention you require 'nomodeset' to stop the system from freezing after a minute or so.

Comment: @pHeLiOn Ok thank you so much for helping me with all these issues.

Comment: No problem. I've learned some interesting things along the way :) One thing that might help figure out the graphics card: It's an HP All-In-One but what is the exact model number? Hopefully there is some detailed info online, but the exact model will be needed to find it. Put it in the question and it might help get an answer.

Comment: Useful information to add to your question: the output of `sudo lshw -c display` and the specific model of your HP All-In-One.